# Solve a PDE with plane polar coordinates (method of separation)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

Solve $∇^2(u) = 0$ in two dimensions for $r < 1$ (in plane polar coordinates), with boundary
conditions $u(1, θ) = A$ for $0 < θ < π$ ,  $0$ for $π < θ < 2π$
where $A$ is a given constant.

I have done the method by separation and found the right equation. Now i am struggling with plugging in the boundary conditions. The bit in particular is the fourier series transformation at the end. Can anyone show a detailed process of the last part.

Comment: Showing your work might help incite answers. Especially because it would circumvent us having to redo work you've already done (considering that this is a somewhat lengthy process to do when one includes explanations).

Answer (score 1):

The separated solutions are
$$
          A_0, (A_n\cos(n\theta)+B_n\sin(n\theta))r^{n},\;\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots
$$
The coefficients $A_n,B_n$ are determined by Fourier series
$$
       u(1,\theta)=       A_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(A_n\cos(n\theta)+B_n\sin(n\theta))
$$